# What is the appropriate use of the DeLong Test when comparing AUC of two different models tested on the same dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, auc

In this scenario there are three datasets. Each dataset has 1000 images of an apple and 1000 images of a banana. Dataset A is used to train machine learning model A to classify whether the image is of an apple or banana. Dataset B is used to train model B. And dataset C is used to test both model A and model B. Afterwards comparing the AUROC of both models in a DeLong Test to see if models are significantly different?

Questions:

1.) Is this the appropriate use of the DeLong Test?

2.) What test could be used when comparing the same model against different datasets to demonstrate that the datasets are significantly different? For example test Model A with dataset B and dataset C and to determine if there is any significant difference.